# c#- System.TypeInitializationException' error

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a program in c# visual studio and when I try to run it it throws an error :

> Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in SagemReader.dll
>
> Additional information: The type initializer for 'SagemReader.SagemReaderAPI' threw an exception.

I tried looking for solution in this thread but the solutions do not work for me, so I had to post a new one.
Here is the section of my code which throws the error:

```
try
{
    readers = new char[-1 + 1][];

    //initailize Smart Card Reader
    Debug.WriteLine("oblSagem");
    oblSagem = SagemReaderAPI.InitSagemReader();
    //oblSagem.Initialize_Reader();
    //Test KC 20140922
    if (!booSagemReaderBusy)
    {
        booSagemReaderBusy = true;
        booCurrentSagemReaderStatusOK = oblSagem.getReaders(ref readers);
    }

    if (!booCurrentSagemReaderStatusOK)
    {
        booSagemReaderBusy = false;
        booPreviousSagemReaderStatusOK = booCurrentSagemReaderStatusOK;
    }
    else
        booSagemReaderBusy = false;

    Debug.WriteLine($"Sagem Busy : {booSagemReaderBusy} ; Current Sagem Status : {booCurrentSagemReaderStatusOK} ; Previous Sagem Status : {booPreviousSagemReaderStatusOK}" );
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    CommonMethods.LogError("MemberInfo()", "[SEGAM ERROR]" + ex);
    booCurrentSagemReaderStatusOK = false;
    if (!booCurrentSagemReaderStatusOK)
        booPreviousSagemReaderStatusOK = booCurrentSagemReaderStatusOK;
}
```

My first instinct is there is no initialization of variable for **oblSagem**.
as it highlights the error line:

```
  oblSagem = SagemReaderAPI.InitSagemReader();
```

The inner exception error hightlights this:

```
CommonMethods.LogError("MemberInfo()", "[SEGAM ERROR]" + ex);
```

With error message:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Common.dll

Additional information: Log Master must be initiate before this method. Check static constructor.
```

I tried initialize it but it won't work.
Is that where I am made my mistake?

Comment: It is probably contain static constructor and throws exception in it

Comment: @eocron or - and this often gets overlooked - static field initializers

Comment: the text you've added seems to tell you everything. It seems that there's a `Log` member somewhere - perhaps on `CommonMethods` - that is currently `null`, and needs to be given a value. I can't see your `Log` member (no double entendre intended), but: look for that. I would start by looking inside the `CommonMethods.LogError` method.

Comment: Should i be looking inside the class of code that I've posted?

Comment: @CookieMonster probably not, no - as I already said: `CommonMethods.LogError` is the first place to look - see what *it touches* - probably a static field that holds the log destination, that hasn't been configured

Comment: I've looked through it, everything seems to check out

Comment: @CookieMonster the runtime disagrees with you. If I had to choose, I'm going to believe the runtime - it really, really knows what a `null` looks like. Have you *stepped through* the method as it fails?

Comment: I am still going through it as we speak. Unless I overlooked the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch the exception. Look at the `.InnerException`. It will *tell you* what the problem is. It will be related to the static constructor (`static SagemReaderAPI() {...}` or field-initializers (of static fields, like `static int _someField = DoSomeStuff();`) of `SagemReader.SagemReaderAPI`, but without that code...

Comment: .Inner exception as in the additional information?

Comment: @CookieMonster when you `catch(Exception ex)`, there is an `ex.InnerException` - this is often null, but in this case it will be the *actual* exception that happened during type initialization. So look at the `.Message` and `.StackTrace` of the `ex.InnerException`

Comment: I caught the exception but can't figure the underlying cause of the problem

Comment: @CookieMonster great! now what is `ex.InnerException.Message` and `ex.InnerException.StackTrace` ?

Comment: look at my edited post

Comment: this is very interesting. CommonMethods.LogError are all not null. Yet gives me the error.

Comment: @CookieMonster `CommenMethods` is a type and `LogError` is a method (presumably), so asking whether they are "null" is a bizarre question - it literally doesn't apply (unless `LogError` is actually a delegate). You need to look *inside* `LogError`

Comment: So in a nutshell, error is due to Null in the LogError method and I have to change it to not Null?

Comment: I am having trouble locating the LogError method since there's thousand of lines of codes in the program along with many c# files class. Is there a quick method to locate that method?

Comment: @CookieMonster press F12 while the text cursor is on that method? or right-click on it and select "go to definition" ?

Comment: Yea but there is a lot of references on that. And it doesn't seem to be in the current .cs file I am looking at. There's a few more .cs files, it could be in there .

Comment: I found these two:     public static void LogError(string functionName, string errorMessage);
        public static void LogError(Exception exception, string functionName = "");

Comment: The rest of the Log error are inside CATCH blocks

Comment: Based on the error: LogMaster should be initializaed before this method, does that mean  i should be looking for logmaster instead?